# How to search for unicode characters in records of DB2?

Tags: search, unicode, db2

I have a table in DB2 say **METAATTRIBUTE** wherein a column say "**content**" might contain any special character including the unicode characters.

For any special character, Eg: "#" I can simply search by :

```
Select * from METAATTRIBUTE where content like '%#%';
```

but how to search for unicode characters like "**u201B**" or "**u201E**" ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about DB2 LUW, the Unicode string literals are designated by the symbols "u&", followed by a regular string literal in single quotes. Unicode code points are designated by an escape character, backslash by default. For example:

```
$ db2 "values u&'\201b'"

1  
---
‛  

  1 record(s) selected.
```

So your query would look like:

```
Select * from METAATTRIBUTE where content like u&'%\201b%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have had the same problem. This worked for me

```
select * 
  from METAATTRIBUTE
 where MEDEDELINGSZONE like '%' || UX'201B' || '%'
```